# string manipulation replace and reverse(for loop)

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char

i am having issue with display the output in different lines of codes how can i do that?

```
package replaceandreverse;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReplaceAndReverse {


 public static void main(String args[])
    { 
    //****************************************************************************************************************************************    

         String newsen="";//parameter 1 will contain the new sentence
         String temp="";//parameter 2 will be use a temporary memory to save the replace string process

        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);      //instantiate scanner
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence:"); //display Enter sentence
        String s = src.nextLine();                 //take user input also string s is the 3rd paramter which saves the string inputed

    //****************************************************************************************************************************************

        System.out.println("Enter the word to be replaced:"); //display Enter the word to be replaced
        String replace = src.next();                          // take user input
        System.out.println("Enter the word with which it is to be replaced:"); //Display Enter the word with which it is to be replaced
        String replacewith = src.next();        //take user input for the letter to with which to replace the previously inputed word.
        s=s+" ";//add to s

    //****************************************************************************************************************************************  
        //loop to perform the replace process
        // is on for loop which contains nested if-else loop
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            char x=s.charAt(i);// turning string to char
            if(x!=' ')
            {
                temp=temp+x;
            }//end of if loop 1
            else
            {
                if(replace.equals(temp))
                {
                    newsen=newsen+replacewith;
                }//end of if loop 2
                else
                {
                    newsen=newsen+temp;
                }//end of else loop 1

                newsen=newsen+" ";
                temp="";

            }//end of else loop 2

        }//end of for loop for the replace process

    //****************************************************************************************************************************************    

        System.out.println("The new sentence is :"+" "+newsen); //display the new sentence with the new sentence

        System.out.print("The reverse sentence is :"); //display the reverse sentence is

    //****************************************************************************************************************************************

        //loop to print the words in reverse
        for(int i=newsen.length()-1; i>=0; i-- )
        {

         System.out.print(newsen.charAt(i)); // display reverse sentence 

        }//end of loop to reverse string

    //****************************************************************************************************************************************

    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use src.nextLine() instead of using src.next() when you are grabbing the input from the user.

Comment: your code will be much simplier if you use already existing methods from Java API: String class has replace(char, char) method, StringBuilder has method for reversig it.

Comment: What issue are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nextLine() function instead of the next(). This will grab everything entered by the user. Therefor if you do the following

```
System.out.println("Enter the word to be replaced:"); //display Enter the word to be replaced
String replace = src.nextLine();  // take the entire user input
System.out.println("Enter the word with which it is to be replaced:"); //Display Enter the word with which it is to be replaced
String replacewith = src.nextLine(); // take the entire user input
```

You get the correct output

```
Enter the sentence:
my name is ryan
Enter the word to be replaced:
name
Enter the word with which it is to be replaced:
pizzapie
The new sentence is : my pizzapie is ryan 
The reverse sentence is : nayr si eipazzip ym
```